# How to print the sum value of gradient in tensorflow?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

```
self.logits =  nn_layers.full_connect_(self.wide_deep_embed, config.num_classes, activation='None', use_bn = True, \
                                       keep_prob=self.keep_prob, name='output_layer')  # predict prob
## loss and optim
#self.loss = nn_layers.cross_entropy_loss_with_reg(self.labels, self.logits)
self.loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(self.labels, self.logits)
tf.summary.scalar('loss', self.loss)

if not opt:
    optim = nn_layers.get_optimizer(config.optimizer, learning_rate=self.learning_rate)
else:
    optim = opt
self.train_op = optim.minimize(self.loss, global_step=self.global_step)

## score & infers
self.infers = self.logits  # predict label
```

Here is a part of my model which is a DNN to do a regression task.
But I find that the model's loss did not change to much after several batches (batch size is 1000 and the whole data is 11 million). 
So I want to print the value of sum gradient in every step, which is the sum of gradients in every batches. How can I modify my code to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can add the gradients to [tensorboard summary](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/summaries_and_tensorboard) on each step:

```
# All gradients of loss function wrt trainable variables 
grads = tf.gradients(self.loss, tf.trainable_variables())
# Summarize all gradients
for grad, var in list(zip(grads, tf.trainable_variables())):
  tf.summary.histogram(var.name + '/gradient', grad)
```

If the gradients are too big, you can report the sum as well:

```
for grad, var in list(zip(grads, tf.trainable_variables())):
  tf.summary.histogram(var.name + '/gradient_sum', tf.reduce_sum(grad))
```

But usually you can detect vanishing gradients without taking a sum: just take a look at the gradients at the early layers of your network.